# Antlr not working with VS2017

Tags: c#, .net-core, antlr4, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to set up a simple project with **Antlr** in **.net core 1.0** project using **VS2017**.

Following https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs, added .g4 file to the project. The project file looks like this,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
     <None Remove="Calculator.g4" />   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4" Version="4.5.4-beta001" />   </ItemGroup>  

   <ItemGroup>
     <AdditionalFiles Include="Calculator.g4" />   
   </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But the document says,

> Locate an existing XML element according to the MSBuild Property
>   column in the table above, or add one if it does not already exist.
>   For example, to generate both the parse tree listener and visitor
>   interfaces and base classes for your parser, update the project item
>   to resemble the following.
>
> ```
> <Antlr4 Include="CustomLanguage.g4">  
> <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator> 
> <CustomToolNamespace>MyProject.Folder</CustomToolNamespace>  
> <Listener>True</Listener>   <Visitor>True</Visitor> </Antlr4>
> ```

There is no any Antlr4 tag in this proj file. Is Antlr not supported in **VS2017**? 
is tehre a good example I can follow to use ANtlr with .net core?

Comment: I just tested 4.6.1-beta001 in several scenarios and it works quite well.

Comment: @LexLi with VS2017?

Comment: Definitely in VS2017 RTM.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, how did you generate "<Antlr4" tag in proj file? Were you able to set the BuildType to "Antlr" for .g4 file?

Comment: VS2017 does not have Antlr Language Support Extension which used to do the trick automatically. (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.ANTLRLanguageSupport).

Comment: there is something called "manually".

Comment: @LexLi, I tried manual approach, then the project wont build.

Comment: Appreciate if you can put the proj file in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is simply all I need in my .NET Standard 1.3 class library project to hold the grammar file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Antlr4 Include="Something.g4">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <Listener>False</Listener>
      <Visitor>False</Visitor>
    </Antlr4>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4" Version="4.6.1-beta001" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Note that you might use a newer Antlr4 package version as 4.6.1 was the only version available when this answer was created.

Comment: Just landed on this, looking for the (non-existent) documentation. 4.6.5-beta001 is the latest version, which removes the dependency on Java as an experimental feature. You need to add `<PropertyGroup>
    <Antlr4UseCSharpGenerator>True</Antlr4UseCSharpGenerator>
  </PropertyGroup>`

Answer (score 4):

I was just looking for the same thing, for .NET Core 2.0.

The current ANTLR4 package version is 4.6.5 Beta 1. In this version the C# generator was ported to C# so the dependency to Java was removed. This is still experimental and has to be enabled manually with :

```
<Antlr4UseCSharpGenerator>True</Antlr4UseCSharpGenerator>
```

Files aren't generated when a `.g4` file is modified. They will be generated when `dotnet build` is called.

File globbing works as expected BUT changing settings like `<Visitor>false</Visitor>` requires a call `dotnet clean` before `dotnet build`.

The default Antlr task options can be found [in the source](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/f62010862bd1e38b3c6e3940931dcde949bdaa91/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4BuildTasks/Antlr4.net40.targets#L73) :

```
<Antlr4>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <CustomToolNamespace Condition="'$(Antlr4IsSdkProject)' != 'True'">$(RootNamespace)</CustomToolNamespace>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <Encoding>UTF-8</Encoding>
  <TargetLanguage>CSharp</TargetLanguage>
  <Listener>true</Listener>
  <Visitor>true</Visitor>
  <Abstract>false</Abstract>
  <ForceAtn>false</ForceAtn>
</Antlr4>
```

Globbing works, so if I want to build all `g4` files and disable visitors, all I have to write is :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Antlr4 Include="**/*.g4" >
    <Visitor>false</Visitor>
  </Antlr4>
</ItemGroup>
```

My entire `csproj` file looks like this :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Antlr4UseCSharpGenerator>True</Antlr4UseCSharpGenerator>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr4">
      <Version>4.6.5-beta001</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <Antlr4 Include="**/*.g4" >
        <Visitor>false</Visitor>
      </Antlr4>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```